# "func2 (func1 arg)", "(func2 . func1) arg" or "func2 $ func1 arg"?

Tags: haskell

I wonder which option would you choose?

```
putStrLn (show randomNum)
putStrLn $ show randomNum
(putStrLn . show) randomNum
```

All options are syntactically correct.

- The brackets ensure that `show` is executed first and `putStrLn` gets only one argument.
- The `$` operator takes the show function and the `randomNum` and executes `show` on `randomNum`, so `putStrLn` gets only one argument.
- The `.` operator takes the `putStrLn` function, the `show` function and the `randomNum` and executes first `show` on `randomNum` and then `putStrLn` on the result.

But what would be more haskell-like or make more sense in this example?

Comment: I think this is much about personal choice. I tend to write `f $ g x`. But with more functions I also write `f . g . h $ x`, moving `$` to the right. I could use `f . g $ x` if  find `f . g` "meaningful". I know I am not 100% consistent in my own style.

Comment: Definitely a stylistic choice. Pick one and apply it consistently.

Comment: This is not a very suitable question for StackOverflow - all are equally "Haskell-like". There is no correct answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
print randomNum
```

Since `print = putStrLn . show`, that's obvious. If you really want to use separate functions, compose then apply.

```
putStrLn . show $ randomNum
```